# Почему не работает :hover? В чем ошибка?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```css
.knopka {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: #7f7;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #369e36;
}


}
.knopka:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #5d5;
  color: #395239;
}
```

```html
<div class="knopka">+</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

7 строка снизу в css, там стоит лишняя фигурная скобка, из-за неё не работает hover